# how to make WPF ListViewItem TextBlock look like button with ItemTemplate?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I want to get ListViewItem Height, BackGround and ForeGround look the same as the application scope default style defines button to look like. How this can be done?

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}">
        </TextBlock>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: It should look like, but not behave like a Button?

Comment: Why not put it in a button? Do you intend to *lie* to your users?

Comment: because this is part of SelectButton https://gist.github.com/loraderon/580405 that i try to get work properly

Comment: yes, no functionality. i'm happy with height, background and foreground

Comment: That button has to react to clicks as well, why not use a button?

Comment: because pressing e.g. 2nd button  on list does not change that button's text to be SelectButton's text.

Comment: i'm also asking how to do this because i'm interested

Comment: Put it in a button with IsHitTestVisible="False" on the button. But don't do that if you're fooling the user -- if clicking on that spot does a button thing of some kind, you're good.

Comment: i have no idea why i should put a button to a list that has only 1 purpose: to select a different text/functionality to a button if selected text/functíonality happens to be wrong. now i have semi-splitbutton that has similar colors etc. all over it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this iss universal but in my environment i did it like this:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Background="{DynamicResource Theme.Button.Background}"
                           Foreground="{DynamicResource Theme.Button.Foreground}"
                           Padding="{DynamicResource Theme.Button.Padding}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```